# Picketlink -How can i implement an authenticating that accept use username or email at same time

Tags: java, security, picketlink

people. 
I need implement authenticating method that accept username or email in form login.

I suspect that is the implementation PasswordCredentialHandler and its AbstractCredentialHandler abstract class.

Has anyone ever experienced this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE 1**

Create a handler based on class PasswordCredentialHandler and Credential based on UsernamePasswordCredential. Add new Handler in store configuration:

```
@Produces 
IdentityConfiguration produceIdentityManagementConfiguration() {
    IdentityConfigurationBuilder builder = new IdentityConfigurationBuilder();

    builder
        .named("default")
        .stores()
        .jpa().addCredentialHandler(EmailPasswordCredentialHandler.class)
        .supportAllFeatures().supportType(UserAccount.class);

    return builder.build();
```

Use a Multiple Authenticator Support or a Custom Authenticator.

In Authentication add logic to identify if user typed username or email, then instantiates a correct Credentials.

**ORIGINAL**

See this official example (from picketlink site):

```
@RequestScoped
@Named
public class AuthenticatorSelector {

   @Inject Instance<CustomAuthenticator> customAuthenticator;
   @Inject Instance<IdmAuthenticator> idmAuthenticator;

   private String authenticator;

   public String getAuthenticator() {

      return authenticator;
    }

   public void setAuthenticator(String authenticator) {
      this.authenticator = authenticator;
   }

   @Produces
   @PicketLink
   public Authenticator selectAuthenticator() {
       if ("custom".equals(authenticator)) {
           return customAuthenticator.get();
        } else {
           return idmAuthenticator.get();
        }
   }
 }
```

You can implement your logic to choose login per email or userid in selectAutheticator method and then `@Produces` and `@Picketlink` annotation provides to framework your custom authenticator (email login) or idm authenticator (ordinary userId login).